# Using meshz command in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I've done the following code:

```
u=linspace(0,1,40);
v=linspace(0,1,40);
[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);
x=u;
y=v.*sqrt(u);
z=x+y+1;
meshz(x,y,z)
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
```

Which gives the following image:

[image]

Now, I'd like to decrease the mesh walls down to the x-y-plane (at `z=0`). I tried the following, which did not work:

```
u=linspace(0,1,40);
v=linspace(0,1,40);
[u,v]=meshgrid(u,v);
x=u;
y=v.*sqrt(u);
z=x+y+1;
meshz(x,y,z)
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
v=axis;
v(5)=0;
axis(v)
```

which yields the following picture:

[image]

I tried a couple of other things, like the last code: adding `hold on`, calling `meshz(x,y,z)` again, but they did not work. How I can extend the `meshz` walls down to the x-y-plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to directly manipulate the `'ZData'` produced by [`meshz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshz.html) via some [handle graphics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html):

```
...
h = meshz(x,y,z);   % Get handle
Z = get(h,'ZData'); % Get ZData
Z([1 end],:) = 0;   % Set border to 0, or other desired value
Z(2:end-1,[1 end]) = 0;
set(h,'ZData',Z);   % Set ZData
...
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I think this may be the only way to do it.  In `meshz.m`, it gets the lower limit for the edges of the "curtains" via `zref = min(min(z(isfinite(z))));`.  So, short of setting one point in the input to a lower value and messing up the shape of the mesh, I don't see any other good way to do it. Good Q and good A. +1s!

Comment: @chappjc: I though of trying something like that and it seemed dirty and probably would be fragile. It is surprising that this function doesn't have an option for this sort of thing built-in. Might be a good thing to [leave feedback with The MathWorks](https://mathworksservicerequest.secure.force.com/cp_case_new) on...

Comment: @horchler: Great move! However, I am curious about the line Z(:,[2 end-1]) = 0;. Using this code, I rotated the figure, then found that the backside was a different color from the largest z to z=1, then from z=1 down to z=0, the same green wall. When I changed this line to Z(:,[1 end])=0;, then I got the same image and the same greenish color from top to bottom. Thoughts?

Comment: @David: Good catch. I transposed some entries. I've fixed that one line in my answer. You can use `Z(:,[1 end]) = 0;` or `Z(2:end-1,[1 end]) = 0;`. The latter just doesn't rewrite zero to the first and last elements which were already set to zero in the line above. It probably no faster.